# ADO API does not list all available service connections

Tags: ado, serviceconnection

The ADO API "https://dev.azure.com///_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=7.0" does not return all service connections those we could see on portal.

Is there way to fetch all available service connections through API?

The ADO API "https://dev.azure.com///_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=7.0" does not return all service connections those we could see on portal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.